# While clicking on an item in Content Editor throws Invalid Certificate exception

Tags: content-editor, xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

Configuring Sitecore 9.0.2 on scaled environment. On the CM environment when we click any of the items related to our website, we see the exception below. Whereas all the Sitecore ootb items in content tree are not throwing this exception. If this is related to xConnect, we verified that all the xConnect URL are accessible from CM with no issues and we are using exact same certificates in the connection string on CM.

[image]

We see the following exception in Sitecore logs:

```
FATAL [Experience Analytics]: Failed to synchronize segments. Message: Ensure definition type did not complete successfully. StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Invalid certificate', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Fri, 22 Feb 2019 18:47:19 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 0
  Expires: -1
}. Details:    at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.GetAll(NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.GetAll(NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsManager.GetSegmentsToSynchronize()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsManager.SynchronizeAllSegments()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Can someone please suggest what this error is all about?

Comment: Can you please check that Analytics are loading or not in dashboard landing page and experience analytics option?

Comment: Thanks for you response Amit. No we see error messages on Experience Analytics dashboard. Where as in logs we see multiple exceptions for Message: The certificate was not found. Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.

Comment: It means browser console will also show JavaScript error, if analytics not loading. Can you please follow the article https://medium.com/@sivalingaamorthy/sitecore-9-xconnect-not-working-having-error-http-error-403-16-b148bb247897.          https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/10/All-about-xConnect-Security/                      to install xConnect certificate properly

Comment: We observed this is happening only when we are set the role:define as "ContentManagement, Processing, Reporting" in web.config. Because we are using same instance for all these three roles. Whereas if we just use "ContentManagement" this works fine. If we want to use the same IIS Instance for all the three Roles, our understanding is setting the "Role:Define" is all we need to do. Any thoughts?.

Comment: As per official doc https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/define-the-server-role.html it's correct. Try to add CM,IS and xConnect on same server and rest on other server.